# 'similar_by_word' did not improve over iterations

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm using Gensim to train a skip-gram word2vec model. The dataset has 1 million sentences, but the vocabulary is of size 200. I would like to see the model accuracy over iterations, so I used `model.wv.similar_by_word` in the callback function to see the scores. But the returned values were not updated over iterations.

The `iter` was set to be `100`.
I tried to change the values of `window` and `size`, but it has no effect.

The model was initialized with callbacks:

```py
Word2Vec(self.train_corpus, workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count(), compute_loss=True, callbacks=[A_CallBack], **word2vec_params)
```

In the class `A_CallBack`, I have something like this:

```py
def on_epoch_end(self, model):
    word, score = model.wv.similar_by_word(word='target_word', topn=1)[0]
    print(word, score)
```

The `word` and `score` were printed out for every epoch, but the values have never changed.

I was expecting the values of them to be updated over iterations, which should make sense?

I'm new to machine learning and word2vec. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various `gensim` similarity functions are optimized via the pre-calculation of unit-length normed vectors, and that pre-calculation is cached in a way that doesn't expect further training to happen.

As a result, when you first check similarities mid-training, as you've done with your callback code, the cache gets filled with the model's early state – and not refreshed after later training. There's a [pending bug](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2260) (as of `gensim-3.8.1` in November 2019) to fix this behavior, in the meantime, you can either:

- refrain from checking similarity-operations until after training is done, or
- manually clear some of the caches after you've done more training. For a plain `Word2Vec` model, it should be enough to do: `model.wv.vectors_norm = None`. (Some other models require extra steps, see the bug discussion for more details.)